# Quantifying magnitude of cosine similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to compare the magnitude of similarity of two sentences by using cosine distance.

More formally, there are three sentences. Sentence X and sentence A, B. I am calculating cosine distance between (A, X) and (B, X). I am trying to find which sentence is more similar to X.

Sentence X has 3 words. Sentence A has 2 words and Sentence B has 3 words. Each word is represented by a fixed size vector. When I do cosine distance between (A,X), I get the following result.

```
array([[ 0.40538598,  0.26931561,  0.42385233],
       [ 0.72361484,  0.3334619 ,  0.66110356]])
```

when I perform cosine distance between (B,X), I get following result:

```
array([[ 0.73618704,  0.25692111,  0.52405244], 
       [ 0.27715719,  0.64043715,  0.4111658 ],
       [ 0.72361484,  0.3334619 ,  0.66110356]])
```

How should I interpret/rank these results? When you perform vector to vector cosine distance, it gives a single value which represents similarity. I am trying to achieve a similar result. I am using sci-kit learn pairwise cosine distance calculator in python.